# Getting error while compiling Glibc-2.28 on LFS fifth module

Tags: linux, centos, linux-from-scratch

Im following LFS 8.3 and at 5th module when i run the configure script of Glibc-2.28 before running make im getting the below error

---

checking for gnumake... no
checking for gmake... gmake
checking version of gmake... 3.82, bad
checking for gnumsgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... no
checking for msgfmt... msgfmt
checking version of msgfmt... 0.18.2, ok
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking version of makeinfo... 5.1, ok
checking for sed... sed
checking version of sed... 4.2.2, ok
checking for gawk... gawk
checking version of gawk... 4.0.2, ok
checking for bison... bison
checking version of bison... 3.0.4, ok
checking if x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc is sufficient to build libc... yes
checking for x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-nm... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-nm
checking for python3... no
checking for python... python
configure: error: 
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: make

### *** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.

The host machine is Centos 7 and i have python 2 by defult and i even installed python 3.4 manually.

Could someone please help me fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74195386/7268445

Answer (score 3):

The issue is "checking version of gmake... 3.82, bad". I had exactly same issue while cross compiling glibc 2.28. You may want to download a newer gmake, install it to a location like /opt/gmake, and add it to the front of PATH environment variable.

```
cd $BIGTMP
curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-4.2.1.tar.gz
tar xvf make-4.2.1.tar.gz
cd make-4.2.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/make && make && make install
export PATH=/opt/make/bin:$PATh
ln -s /opt/make/bin/make /opt/make/bin/gmake
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have also encountered the exactly same problem as Lijo, and the direction of solution by jin is right, but the make path is quite different.

In my pc, the make installed target path is "/usr/local/bin". So I suggest you pay attention to the output for the make installation command line output for the exact installed path.